# Modifying not_null to disallow comparisons to nullptr

Tags: c++, null, cpp-core-guidelines

I'm trying to get a compile-time check for the assignment and testing against null.  Reason is I'm using a "magic" non-null pointer to represent a disengaged state for something, and it's easy to forget it's using that magic pointer and mistakenly assign and test for nullptr.  *(Especially since that was what the code had been using historically.)*

Figuring this was a problem people had already solved, I searched and found `not_null` as [part of the C++ Core Guidelines](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2016/06/01/using-the-not_null-template.aspx), which sounded promising.  Here's an MIT-licensed implementation from Microsoft:

https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL/blob/5cbde3008aa43a9c5f6c219ee15b8388336d4433/include/gsl/pointers#L55

But it only stops assignments to nullptr, not comparisons:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "include/gsl/gsl"

int main() {
    int i;
    gsl::not_null<int*> ptr (&i);
    /* gsl::not_null<int*> ptr_error (nullptr); */ // this errors

    if (ptr != nullptr)
       std::cout << "No compile error on compare--this prints\n";
}
```

That's...unfortunate.  :-/

1. Isn't the point of the core guidelines to help programmers encode the semantics of the program?  Doesn't someone testing the pointer against null and making decisions based on that suggest they don't know what they're doing, and the source code may well be in error?
2. What's a good minor edit to the `not_null` to change it to disallow these comparisons, e.g. `nullptr == ptr`, `ptr == nullptr`, etc?  Brute force I'd just `= delete;` some overloads to == and != until it gave errors in the case I wanted, but my hope from using pre-written code was that someone would have thought about it and done it more generally "right".

Comment: I could picture a generic function taking *some pointer-like type*. The generic function wouldn't know the pointer can't be null; checking it might be sensible.

Comment: @chris True, but only for templated functions. And how would "breaking their expectation of what pointers can be tested against" be so different from breaking their expectation of what assignments are legal? I think it should be the caller's responsibility to coerce not_nulls to plain pointers (or pointer references). Otherwise it really sacrifices a lot of the semantic value I'd imagine not_null is supposed to be offering. In the case I describe, every usage outside this hypothetical category of templated functions would represent a bug. What's the type used for, anyway, if not catching bugs?

Answer (score 1):

One of the reason you can do this is probably because sometimes you might get a pointer/smart pointer and want to compare it to the `gsl::not_null` and/or pass the `gsl::not_null` in a templated function (which is definitely not aware of what `gsl::not_null` offers) :

```
template<class Lhs, class Rhs>
bool hasSameValue(Lhs lhs, Rhs rhs){
  if(lhs == nullptr || rhs == nullptr)
    return lhs == rhs;

  return *lhs == *rhs;
}

gsl::not_null<int*> ptr = /* [...] */;
shared_ptr<int> sptr = /* [...] */;
hasSameValue(ptr, sptr);
```

**If you still want to disallow checks w/ `nullptr` :**

```
bool operator==(std::nullptr_t nptr) = delete;
bool operator!=(std::nullptr_t nptr) = delete;
```

Marking them as deleted should be enough. Note that `gsl::not_null` must not inherit from a class that defines them in order to do so. If it inherits from a class that does define them, simply throw an exception (even though it will be a runtime error only).

Comment: It's true that such functions could exist--though they'd have to be templated.  But I feel it's the caller's responsibility in that case to coerce it to a reference to an ordinary pointer.  Otherwise it's really undermining the relevance of what not_null brings to the table for compile-time checking...

Comment: It is true, I'll add something regarding disallowing comparison w/ `nullptr`

Comment: Yup, well [see note above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51057099/modifying-not-null-to-disallow-comparisons-to-nullptr/51057253?noredirect=1#comment89105462_51057253) about how disabling just the member comparisons doesn't handle the case when the nullptr is on the left.  As I mention I was just curious from an educational standpoint if there was some way to get the errors more "naturally" by making the existing global != and == overloads do the work.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to implement equality operators for the `std::nullptr_t` type:

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Test
{
public:
  Test(int value) : value(value) {}

  bool operator == (std::nullptr_t n)
  {
      return value == 0;
  }

  bool operator != (std::nullptr_t n)
  {
      return value != 0;
  }

private:
  int value;    
};

int main()
{
    Test a(0);
    Test b(1);
    std::cout << (a == nullptr) << ", " << (b == nullptr) << "\n";
    std::cout << (a != nullptr) << ", " << (b != nullptr) << "\n";
}
```

or if you want a compile error just delete the same operators.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, one wants to handle `nullptr == ptr` also, so you can't just have member overloads...you need global overloads also.  So I was curious if there was some cross-cutting one-line way of doing it.  *(And also just to raise the question of "why doesn't it do this already...)*

Comment: OK,  that only makes 4 overloads to implement/delete though? its not that strenuous surely?

Comment: It's not about the "strenuousness".  You mentioned 2, and due to some amount of experience I knew to say "well, there's *at least* two more points to consider".  Someone who knows more than I do might be able to think 
 of other angles of consideration.  That's why we ask questions.  I was hoping for some single-line-change that would be able to inform the existing global comparisons in the class so they'd not consider nullptr as a candidate...

Comment: hmm, actually without any operators at all `nullptr` comparisons already don't compilie in my testing. Presumably you have some other operators already defined? We need a [mcve] here I think

Comment: My example is minimal and complete.  Whether it's verifiable in this case is now on you, to present the error you receive when compiling it.  In my case I compiled it with **g++ (Ubuntu 7.2.0-8ubuntu3.2) 7.2.0** without error.

Comment: @AlanBirtles Could you post your test code and the corresponding compiler error(s).  I for one would be interested .

Comment: @PaulSanders just the code above with the operators deleted failed to compile on http://cpp.sh

Comment: Did you have all the relevant dependencies?  I got: [3:27: fatal error: include/gsl/gsl: No such file or directory](http://cpp.sh/5leq4).

Comment: @PaulSanders C++ Core Guidelines is not part of the standard distribution at this time.  In order to reproduce the issue with the implementation cited in the question, one has to use the source from the link provided.  With GCC: at the command line, `git clone https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL` then make the file as `test.cpp` and say `g++ test.cpp -IGSL/include -o test`, and `./test` to run and observe the printed output.

Comment: Yes, after just a quick google around I can't find an online compiler that supports it.  I'm signing off now, happy hacking guys.